# Trying to send keystroke to game, but game is ignoring

Tags: c#

So I know this is a topic that has been touched on quite a lot on this website and this is yet another question devoted to it.

I'm trying to send keystrokes to a certain game and I believe the game to be ignoring my keystrokes. I know I've found the window because before I send the keystroke, I set the game to the foreground and that is working. I've tried SendKeys.Send, SendWait, and am currently trying the Windows API via SendMessage, and that's not working either. I'm using a method that I found via another user on SO. Here's what I'm working with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace KeySendTest2
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);



        public static void SendKeyStroke(IntPtr window, ushort key)
        {
            const uint WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
            const uint WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

            SendMessage(window, WM_KEYDOWN, ((IntPtr)key), (IntPtr)0);
            SendMessage(window, WM_KEYUP, ((IntPtr)key), (IntPtr)0);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow("the class here", null);
            SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            while (true)
            {
                SendKeyStroke(hWnd, (ushort)Keys.F3); // Doesn't work
                //SendKeys.SendWait(Keys.F3); -- Also doesn't work
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The game is a Windows application that is not a web browser. Does anyone have any idea that could point me in the right direction of why it might be ignoring the keystrokes? I know it can be done as there are several utilities built for the game that send keystrokes to the game, but they aren't open source so I have no way of seeing what method they are using.

Answer (score 0):

In spite of official recommendations, many games don't use the message loop for input.  Rather, they use the depreciated [DirectInput API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectInput) or other means.

I have had success using the [AutoIT](http://autoit.com) library [from C# code](http://autoitsourcecode.blogspot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-autoit-in-c.html) for this purpose.

Comment: Well the game is from 1997. I'll see if I can't give both of these methods a try, thanks.

Comment: Then very likely it uses DirectInput